# kernel panic - no idea how to fix

Tags: linux, centos

My Alfresco server suddenly stopped booting and gave me this message upon bootup:

```
ACPI: Getting cpuindex for acpiid 0x5
ACPI: Getting cpuindex for acpiid 0x6
ACPI: Getting cpuindex for acpiid 0x7
Red Hat nash version 5.1.19.6 starting
    Reading all physical volumes. This may take a while...
    Found volume group "VolGroup00" using metadata type lvm2
    3 logical volume(s) in volume group "VolGroup00" now active
ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
ata1.00: BMDMA stat 0x24
ata1.00: cmd c8/00:00:3d:19:86/00:00:00:00:00/e0 tag 0 dma 131072 in
ata1.00: status: { DRDY DF ERR }
ata1.00: error: { ABRT }
ata1.00: revalidation failed (errno=-5)
ata1.00: revalidation failed (errno=-5)
ata1.00: revalidation failed (errno=-5)
JBD: Failed to read block at offset 21726
EXT3-f: error loading journal.
Buffer I/O error on device dm-0, logical block 2057
mount: error mounting /dev/root on /sysroot as ext3: Invalid argument
setuproot: moving /dev failed: No such file or directory
setuproot: error mounting /proc: No such file or directory
setuproot: error mounting /sys: No such file or directory
switchroot: mount failed: No such file or directory
Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!
```

This is my first time encountering this. Is it safe to say that the problem is with the hard drive? I'd like to try and mount the hard drive to another system so I can retrieve the files. How do I fix this system? Or, should I just start creating a new server to replace this one if you think this is irrepairable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm really sorry for your loss.

That disk has died.

```
ata1.00: cmd c8/00:00:3d:19:86/00:00:00:00:00/e0 tag 0 dma 131072 in
ata1.00: status: { DRDY DF ERR }
ata1.00: error: { ABRT }
```

That's pretty much the swan song of a dying SATA disk.

You should probably create a new server, restore from your last known good backup, and carry on.

You might want to investigate RAID for multiple disks on your server to give you  resilience against disk failure..

Comment: R.I.P., faithful drive.

Comment: Yes, I think that's it. It's an old server that I inherited.

Comment: I was just told that there are very important files that need to be retrieved. What are the chances that the files are recoverable?

Comment: @dashmug You might get a few things off the drive, or you might just make it worse. If it's that important, send it to a professional data recovery service.

Comment: Ouch! It's really bye, bye then.